# Reference to a complex data element

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a model that is represented by a class.

e.g. the model of a car:

```
export class Car
{
    public name : string;
    public color: string;
    public power : number;
    public service : boolean;
}
```

Cars are stored in a list.

```
cars : Array <Car>;
```

Now I would like to have a function that changes one attribute of a car.

e.g. the color of the 1st car or the name of the 2nd.

What is the best way to reference to a car AND its attribute as a parameter for that function?

As far I know e.g.

```
 cars [0].name
```

would pass the value and not a reference inside my function.

I can point to a car by the index of the array. For the attribute I can take a string that I need to interpret. But thats not very smart I think.

Any better ideas?

Comment: If your Car object does not have any function then use Interface instead of Class.  Use javascript arrays `cars: Car[]`. Then you will be able to simply `cars[0].name=...`

Comment: This is a very broad question. It really depends upon what you want to do. My only recommendation is that you read up on immutable objects in JavaScript, and the problems of change detection on objects that mutate.

Answer (score 2):

[Advanced Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types) to the rescue (specifically indexed types)!  You can modify dynamic properties in a type safe way:

```
interface Car {
    name: string;
    color: string;
    power: number;
    service: boolean;
}

class CarContainer {
    public cars: Car[] = [];

    updateCar<K extends keyof Car, V extends Car[K]>(index: number, key: K, value: V) {
        let selectedCar = this.cars[index];
        if (selectedCar) {
            selectedCar[key] = value;
        } 
    }
}


let c = new CarContainer();
c.cars.push({
    name: "Old Jalopy",
    color: "black",
    power: 0,
    service: false,
});

// Time for a power upgrade!
c.updateCar(0, "name", "Tesla Roadster");
c.updateCar(0, "power", 100000000);
```